# Does service.schedule() method blocks other threads from running?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have two newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor, scheduledService1 and scheduledService2.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Runnable task1 = () -> System.out.println("Hello zoo1");
Callable<String> task2 = () -> "Monkey";

ScheduledFuture<?> result1 = scheduledService1.schedule(task1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(result1.get());

Future<?> result2 = scheduledService1.schedule(task2, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(result2.get());

Runnable task3 = () -> System.out.println("Hello zoo2");
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledService2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduledService2.schedule(task3, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//blocked by scheduledService1?

ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
es.execute(() -> System.out.println("new single thread executor"));

System.out.println("main thread");
```

This outputs:

```
Hello zoo1
null
Monkey
main thread
new single thread executor
Hello zoo2
```

Based on the output, it seems that `scheduledService1` blocks the main thread and `es` thread. Why is this so? Since "Hello zoo2" is printed last (from `scheduledService2` task), why does it not block main and `es` thread as well. These are below the `scheduledService2` declaration after all. Are my assumptions correct that only the first `ScheduledExecutorService` will block other threads and not the succeeding `ScheduledExecutorService` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScheduledFuture<?> result1 = scheduledService1.schedule(task1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Neither scheduling `task1`, nor its execution will block the calling thread, as `scheduledService1` uses its own background thread pool.

But, calling `get` on a `Future` will block the caller until the result is ready (i.e. the scheduled task has run to completion):

```
System.out.println(result1.get()); // this will block for 5 seconds
```